# sailsjs delete/update multiple rows

Tags: sails.js, multiple-instances, delete-row

I am working on sailsjs, I have generated api model and controller. I am just wondering if I can post and create many entries of this model instead of use curl in commandline over and over. also does this restful interface support a delete method and update method for multiple rows at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this information is in the docs http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api

You can create multiple records at once in a single post by default.  Post an array of entries to create.

For update and delete, I believe you will need to tweak the blueprints to look for an array of ids.  Waterline, the underlying ORM of Sails supports create and delete on multiple rows, though watch out for  breaking associations http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/update.html?q=notes

In order to override blueprints, create your own blueprints in `api/blueprints/` e.g. `api/blueprints/update.js` and make them look for an array of ids.  You'll probably want to start with the default blueprints https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions.

Also, you'll need to define your own routes as the `update` and `delete` actions are by default bound to the `PUT 'controller/:id'` and `DELETE 'controller/:id'` respectively, which inherently allows for only a single id.

Comment: When I send a raw json object (using postman) to the create method of my api, I get a validation response that says my properties are null. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I'm able to use Postman so probably something in your controller or in the blueprint create controller is either stripping out info or trying to deserialize the JSON using a different format.  Maybe open another question with more info?

Comment: I get the same problem as OneHoopyFrood, did you manage to solve it?